# Array returns nothing from mysql if more than one value selected

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

How do I get all the results of my query to show? If my $author prints as Array ( [0] => 1 ) the query pulls correct data. However, if my $author prints as Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8  ) or any combination of values received from my form, then it returns empty.

The array prints correctly, so I am moving from that point forward and assuming the problem is the query but cannot figure it out.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM estudos";
if (isset($author)){
    $query.=" WHERE author='" . implode ($author) ."'";
    print_r ($author);
}
```

Here is my php and html...

```
$results=$dbclient->query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

<?php 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    echo"<tr><td class='name'>$row[name]</td>";
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE author='" . implode ($author) ."'";` WTF?!? Have you ever come across SQL's `IN`

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually, I am VERY new at this, so I must say, no I have not. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I will check it out though.

Comment: [SQL IN Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `glue` parameter for [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode). Without that, your `$query` would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM estudos WHERE author='FooBarBaz'
```

This is a syntactically valid SQL query, but it doesn't do what you want.

You're probably looking for the  [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause.

```
$query .= " WHERE author IN (" . implode (',', $author) .")";
```

Note that I haven't fixed the [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php) vulnerabilities in your query. I recommend you switch to MySQLi or PDO and start using parameterized queries to be safe from SQL injection.

Comment: hihi! :) `implode()` again.. however, you might give an example for a prepared statement here...

Comment: I just tried this, but I still only get results for one item in array.

Comment: @JeremyTyler: Can you try to `echo $query;` before execution and post the output?

Comment: @JeremyTyler: Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IN condition in your SQL Query

```
$query.=" WHERE author IN (" . implode (',',$author) .")";
```

[SQL IN Condition](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

if author is string your code will be

```
 if (isset($author)){
$query . = "("
foreach ($author as $value)
{
    $query .= "'".$value."',";
}
$query = substr($query,0,-1);
$query .= ")";

    print_r ($author);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably author names will be string and you should format it it like below

```
    IN ('author1', 'author2')
```

A php function which will help you

```
function quote($str) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}
$authors = array('author1', 'author2', 'author3');
WHERE author IN (implode(',', array_map('quote', $authors)));
```